# Raven instance embedded / hosted in UI - limit resource greediness

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, ravendb

We are running an `EmbeddableDocumentStore` within a UI process.

Under some circumstances, master data or synced data is loaded into the store from a server. Especially in those situations, Raven does such a *good job* at utilizing available resources that it seems to starve the main UI thread - we are talking CPU cycles mainly. The message pumping takes a heavy blow, making the UI very unresponsive. I am quite certain that nothing from Raven actually runs on the UI thread.

I'd rather have the batch loading and data syncing run at a slower pace, if it buys me a better UI responsiveness.

My own thoughts on what could be done revolved around core affinity of threads, that seems to be a huge bag of things to consider.

My question is if there are any promising customization possibilities / configuration settings in Raven to actually bring down the cycles it utilizes. A bonus would be if the time when Raven utilizes less cycles could be influenced programmatically (i.e. return to normal when bulk storing is done).

Comment: Consider posting your question on RavenDB group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ravendb

Comment: yeah, but the summary warns me of cross-posting ;)

Comment: Ayende is usually monitoring ravendb tag so you should get an authoritative answer soon...

Answer (score 2):

Try setting **Raven/MaxNumberOfParallelIndexTasks** configuration option to limit how many cores are used.

I bet the CPU is used by indexing process, not the actual document storing.